# Video isn't of allowed type (allowed types: video/mp4), Shrine, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, shrine

I'm trying to validate my videos to only allow .mp4 videos to be uploaded. I'm using Shrine to do this. Videos upload no problem without validations, but if I add the validation code the error displays: `Video isn't of allowed type (allowed types: video/mp4)`

Here is my code:

**video_uploader.rb**

```
require "streamio-ffmpeg"

class VideoUploader < Shrine
  plugin :processing
  plugin :versions

  plugin :determine_mime_type
  plugin :cached_attachment_data
  plugin :remove_attachment
  plugin :add_metadata

  add_metadata do |io|
    video = FFMPEG::Movie.new(io.path)
    { "duration" => video.duration}
  end

  metadata_method :duration

  Attacher.validate do
    validate_max_size 200.megabyte, message: "is too large (max is 1 MB)"
    validate_mime_type_inclusion ['video/mp4']
  end
end
```

The video I'm trying to upload is definitely a .mp4 and I have this exact validation working in my `image_uploader.rb` file, so I'm not sure why it isn't working with my `video_uploader.rb`. Any ideas?

Comment: When you add a `puts get.mime_type` statement inside the `Attacher.validate` block, what does it print out?

Comment: It shows that it is a `video/mp4`. No idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Could you try `p get.mime_type`, maybe there might be some unwanted whitespace in the string.